# Windows Phone 8 icon depending on configuration (Release, Debug)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

is it possible to change the icon depending on the configuration in visual studio?

I want use a "Release" icon and a "Debug" icon for a windows phone 8.0 app.

In the Manifest i can only set a path:

```
<IconPath IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">ApplicationIcon.png</IconPath>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean having different icons for `Release` and `Debug` modes?

Comment: Yes two different icons!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a pre-build step which copies the desired icon in based on the build configuration. Something like the following:

copy $(ProjectDir)\Assets\ApplicationIcon.scale-100.$(Configuration).png $(ProjectDir)\Assets\ApplicationIcon.scale-100.png

Then provide ApplicationIcon.scale-100.release.png and ApplicationIcon.scale-100.debug.png. You may also need a dummy ApplicationIcon.scale-100.png to make sure it's included as Content. You probably don't want to include the .debug. and .release. versions as content and may want to pull them from a separate directory.